# Ansible - Push authorized key to multiple host groups with different passwords

Tags: ansible, key-authentication, remote-management

I want to push a new user's public key to a host invetory using Ansible.
For that, a playbook was created like the following example.

```
---
- name: vms1 - Authorize hosts with pub key
  hosts: vms1
  tasks:
    - name: Copy ssh pub key to remote host
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: user1
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/controluser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"

- name: vms2 - Authorize hosts with pub key
  hosts: vms2
  tasks:
    - name: Copy ssh pub key to remote host
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: user2
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/controluser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"

- name: vms3 - Authorize hosts with pub key
  hosts: vms3
  tasks:
    - name: Copy ssh pub key to remote host
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: user3
        state: present
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/controluser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

The inventory goes like this. (with many more hosts)

```
[vms1]
192.168.7.211
192.168.7.212
192.168.7.213

[vms2]
192.168.7.21
192.168.7.22
192.168.7.23

[vms3]
192.168.7.111
192.168.7.112
192.168.7.113
```

Each play has its own host group and its own user.
The playbook can be started with the following command.

```
ansible-playbook -k -i inventory playbook.yml
```

When using `-k` option, it only asks the SSH password once.
The issue I have is that the password is different for each group.
Therefore, I would like to input the password for each play.

How could the password be requested for each play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"How could the password be requested for each play?"***

A: Use the variable *ansible_password*. For example, put the variable into the playbooks' *vars*

```yaml
- hosts: vms1
  vars:
    ansible_password: connection passwd for vms1
  tasks:
    - name: Copy ssh pub key to remote host
      ...

- hosts: vms2
  vars:
    ansible_password: connection passwd for vms2
  tasks:
    - name: Copy ssh pub key to remote host
      ...
```

See details

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t connection ssh
```

---

Read the passwords in the first play and use them later. For example, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[vms1]
192.168.7.211
192.168.7.212
192.168.7.213

[vms2]
192.168.7.21
192.168.7.22
192.168.7.23

[vms3]
192.168.7.111
192.168.7.112
192.168.7.113
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: "Password for {{ item }}"
          register: out
          loop: "{{ groups|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
        - set_fact:
            passwords: "{{ dict(out.results|json_query('[].[item, user_input]')) }}"
        - debug:
            var: passwords
      run_once: true

- hosts: vms1
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_password: "{{ passwords.vms1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy ssh pub key to remote host by '{{ ansible_password }}'"
      run_once: true

- hosts: vms2
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_password: "{{ passwords.vms2 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy ssh pub key to remote host by '{{ ansible_password }}'"
      run_once: true

- hosts: vms3
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_password: "{{ passwords.vms3 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy ssh pub key to remote host by '{{ ansible_password }}'"
      run_once: true
```

prompts the user for the passwords in the first play and uses them later

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
[pause]
Password for vms1:
passwd for vms1^Mok: [192.168.7.211] => (item=vms1)
[pause]
Password for vms2:
passwd for vms2^Mok: [192.168.7.211] => (item=vms2)
[pause]
Password for vms3:
passwd for vms3^Mok: [192.168.7.211] => (item=vms3)

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.7.211]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.7.211] => 
  passwords:
    vms1: passwd for vms1
    vms2: passwd for vms2
    vms3: passwd for vms3

PLAY [vms1] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.7.211] => 
  msg: Copy ssh pub key to remote host by 'passwd for vms1'

PLAY [vms2] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.7.21] => 
  msg: Copy ssh pub key to remote host by 'passwd for vms2'

PLAY [vms3] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.7.111] => 
  msg: Copy ssh pub key to remote host by 'passwd for vms3'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
192.168.7.111: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
192.168.7.21:  ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
192.168.7.211: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```